# length of modules in arbitrary exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative, noetherian ring. Given the exact sequence of $R$-modules of finite length  $ 0 \rightarrow M_0 \rightarrow M_1 \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_3 \rightarrow 0 $. Is there an equation, connecting the lengths of the modules like in the case of short exact sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a short exact sequence of finite length modules $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, it holds that $l(B)=l(A)+l(C)$.

Split your sequence into two short exact ones:
\begin{gather}
0\to M_0\to M_1\to K\to 0\\
0\to K\to M_2\to M_3\to 0
\end{gather}
Then $l(K)=l(M_1)-l(M_0)$ and $l(K)=l(M_2)-l(M_3)$, so we get that
$$
l(M_0)-l(M_1)+l(M_2)-l(M_3)=0
$$
which generalizes the relation for short exact sequences.

This goes on by easy induction.

Answer (score 1):

In these situations, the alternating sum of the lengths is zero. Here,
$$l(M_0)-l(M_1)+l(M_2)-l(M_3)=0.$$
One can split this into two exact sequences
$$0\to M_0\to M_1\to N\to 0$$
and
$$0\to N\to M_2\to M_3\to 0$$
with the same $N$, also of finite length, and
$$l(N)=l(M_1)-l(M_0)=l(M_2)-l(M_3)$$
etc.